# Query and Sort in MongoDB for a many-to-many relationship

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongodb-query, database

Suppose I have a relationship between `users`, `posts`, `likes`. A user can like a post and a post can be liked by many users.

My goal is to be able to design a db structure in MongoDB such that I can quickly query for all the posts a user has liked AND sort/filter them in the multiple ways listed below (not at the same time - think a dropdown that lets you change the sort order of your search results)

1. Order in which posts were liked
2. Filter and order by various `post` attributes - such as title, number of post responses, when the post was created, etc

Suppose the number of posts is in the order of 100,000 and each post will have on the order of 100-1000 likes

Possible solutions I've thought of:

1) `likes` are embedded in `posts`.

This allows #2 to be dealt with easily because you just have an index over `likes.user_id` and over whatever other post attributes you need. This is also fast, because you only need to run one query.

However, this makes it impossible to sort by when a user liked something (AFAIK).

2) `likes` are a separate collection with attributes `post_id`, `account_id`.

This allows #1 to be dealt with easily since you can just sort by _id. However, unless you duplicate & cache `post` attributes into the `like` document, it becomes impossible to handle #2. This is possible but really not ideal. Additionally, this is slower to query. You'd need to run two queries - one to query the `like` collection, then a `post` query using $in: [post_ids].

Are there any other solutions/designs I should consider? Am I missing anything in these proposed solutions?

Comment: Denormalize. With NoSQL it is common practice to have one piece of  information in several places. So you can, for example, combine both solutions and have likes embedded as well as in separate table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a denormalized version of #2. Have a `like` document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(...),
    "account_id" : 1234,
    "post_id" : 4321,
    "ts" : ISODate(...),
    // additional info about post needed for basic display
    "post_title" : "The 10 Worst-Kept Secrets of Cheesemongers"
    // etc.
}
```

With an index on `{ "account_id" : 1, "ts" : 1 }`, you can efficiently find `like` documents for a specific user ordered by like time.

```
db.likes.find({ "account_id" : 1234 }).sort({ "ts" : -1 })
```

If you put the basic info about the post into the `like` document, you don't need to retrieve the post document until, say, the user clicks on a link to be shown the entire post.

The tradeoff is that, if some `like`-embedded information about a post changes, it needs to be changed in every `like`. This could be nothing or it could be cumbersome, depending on what you choose to embed and how often posts are modified after they have a lot of likes.

Comment: This seems like a good solution, but what if the post data is updated? How efficient would it be to update every like? would this be a bulk update mongo function?

Answer (score 0):

Your first option seems quite good to me. It deals with both of your requirements nicely. 
as,

1. You need to sort the comments, posts based on attributes of post,comment which is possible to through aggregations
2. You need to filter the documents(posts) based on some attributes which is also possible.

Disadvantage of 2 collections are you need to run 2 queries for getting a piece of data. NoSQL databases gives you flexibility to store related data at one place and provides best performance for the same. By not using benefits of NoSQL you wont achieve optimized performance.

Do not think from RDBMS perspective (forget normalization). If you need more performance optimization with first option go with indexing, sharding (with shard key as alphabets range, geography etc.)

Comment: #1 doesnt let you sort by the order in which a post was liked. The embedded array has schema: `like: {account_id: ObjectId, time: Date}`. If you need all the posts by a certain account_id in the order they were liked by that account, this is not possible.

Comment: have you heard of unwind? Which will make #1 possible according to me.

Comment: That's not very efficient? You'd have to unwind each one every time.

Comment: See you have 2 choices, 1. performance 2. easiness in storing the data. Generally NoSQL are designed for easiness i.e. storing related data together. Performance can achieved through efficient querying, indexing, sharding. There is no point in storing related data in 2 different collections where you need to query on both collections like a join. (instead of this why don't you use RDBMS then)

Comment: I would not recommend this option - #2 is difficult, requiring a very inefficient aggregation query, using an unwind, as the OP says.